# Confused about join and split on Perl

Tags: perl

I just started with Perl and I'm confused about when to use `join` or `split` to fill an array with a Linux command result.

I'm learning from a book and this brings these examples.

Example 1:

```
$cmd = `host google.com`;

@arrayCmd = join(/\n/, $cmd);

foreach $i (@arrayCmd) {

  if ( $i =~ / has address / ) {

    $i =~ /.*\s([0-9\.]+)\s.*/;

    my $ip = $1;

    if ( $ip =~ /[0-9\.]+/ ) {

      print "La IP es: " . $ip . "\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}

exit;
```

Example 2:

```
$max = 80;

$sisdev = "/dev/sda5";

$comando = `df -k`; # cargamos las líneas del comando a una variable

@lns = split(/\n/, $comando); # separamos cada línea y las colocamos
                              # como elementos de un array

foreach $linea ( @lns ) { # por cada $linea del array @lns

  if ( $linea =~ /$sisdev/ ) {

    $linea =~ /.*\s([0-9]+)\%\s.*/;
    $valor = $1;                      # buscamos la columna y
                                      # extraemos el valor
    if ( $valor >= $max ) { # comparamos el valor
                            # con el umbral

      print "Alarma!: $sisdev en $valor\%. Igual o por encima del umbral de $max\% \n";
    }
  }
}

exit;
```

Why use `join` at the first example and `split` at the second example?
Thanks.

Comment: Throw the book in the trash can. What is the title of it?

Comment: You are right to be confused. `split` operates on a regular expression and a scalar to produce a list, as in the first example, not `join`. `join` operates on a scalar and a list and produces a scalar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code

```
@arrayCmd = join(/\n/, $cmd);
```

is incorrect, and will not work properly. The author meant to use `split`; with that change, the example looks like it'd work.

A quick explanation of the differences, because the book is clearly doing a poor job of it:

- `$combined = join($separator, @items)` **joins** all of the items in `@items` together, putting `$separator` in between each one, and returns a single combined string.
- `@pieces = split(/regex/, $string)` **splits up** `$string` in each place that the regex matches, and returns an array of the cut-up strings. (And anything that the regex captured.)

Answer (score -1):

you can also get output form your first program using split for that you need to do minor change in first program. you need to use $i =~ /.*\s([0-9.]+)/  instead of $i =~ /.*\s([0-9.]+\s.*)/ Because when you use split that time '\n' is not include into array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$cmd = `host google.com`;

@arrayCmd = split(/\n/, $cmd);

foreach $i (@arrayCmd) {
  if ( $i =~ / has address / ) {
    $i =~ /.*\s([0-9\.]+)/;
    my $ip = $1;
    if ( $ip =~ /[0-9\.]+/ ) {

      print "La IP es: " . $ip . "\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}

exit;
```